# Rouche theorem to $5e^{z + 1} + 3z^{2018} - 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's define $\Delta(0, 1):=\{z \in \mathbb C: |z| < 1\}$ and function $f(z) := 5e^{z + 1}+ 3z^{2018} - 1$.

I want to examine how many zeroes of function $f$ we have on $\Delta(0, 1)$.

**My solution**

In Rouche theorem we want to check the behavior of our function on $\partial \Delta(0, 1) = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z| = 1\}$. So, for $|z| = 1$ we have that:

$$|5e^{z + 1} - 1| \ge |5e^{z + 1}| - 1 = 5|e^z||e| - 1 = 5e^2 - 1 \ge 3 = |3z^{2018}|$$

So function $5e^{z + 1} + 3z^{2018} - 1$ has as many zeroes as function $5e^{z + 1} - 1$ on $\Delta(0, 1)$ We have to check whether the solution belong to this set:

$$5ez^{z + 1} = 1 \Rightarrow z = \ln(\frac 1 5) - 1 \in \Delta(0, 1)$$

So our function has $1$ root on $\Delta(0, 1)$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: How do you show that $\ln(1/5)-1\in\Delta(0,1)$???

Comment: You are missing a modulus sign here: $||5 e^{z+1}| - |1||$.

Comment: Also $|e^z|\ne e$.